# pecl_http extension not loading

Tags: nginx, linode, php, pecl

For some reason pecl_http extension is not showing up in my test.php file with contains:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I just installed pecl_http using:

> pecl install pecl_http

The install was successful and I verified it by running:

> pecl list

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package   Version State
mongo     1.2.10  stable
pecl_http 1.7.4   stable
```

I then located my php.ini file using:

> php -i | grep 'Configuration File'

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

I edited it in vim and added:

> extension=http.so

Finally I restarted Nginx and PHP-FastCGI:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
/etc/init.d/php-fastcgi stop
/etc/init.d/php-fastcgi start
```

My PHP extension_dir is :

> /usr/lib/php5/20090626

I verified that "http.so" is located in that directory.

**Any ideas why it's not loading?**

My machine is running a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit Profile on Linode. The only other extensions I have installed are New Relic and Mongo.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure try loading extansion using full path: `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/http.so`

Comment: @c2h5oh nope same results

Comment: What happens when you run `echo http_get("http://www.google.com");` in a PHP script? When you filter your phpinfo command with `http`, do you see things like `http_request` listed?

Comment: @qweet I get this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get()

Comment: @qweet php -i | grep 'http_request' returns the following: http_request => N/A => 0 => 0
http_request_datashare => GLOBAL => 1 => 0
http_request_pool => N/A => 0 => 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your phpini file paths:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

CLI is the Command Line interface. Check phpinfo() from your webserver and edit the correct php.ini.

Comment: Thanks that did it. My path showed: /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else who may have arrived here looking for an answer but the accepted one didn't fit your case - I may have your solution!

I didn't have a setup problem - at least not to my knowledge. I am running nginx + php5-fpm. My php.ini file was correctly configured and all my other extensions were working properly - test it with phpinfo() or php --ini.

My problem with pecl_http (HttpRequest) was the extension's version (2.0.4). Check your version by running in the command line

```
pecl list
```

I was unable to get pecl_http-2.0.4 to work, but I was able to run

`pecl uninstall pecl_http`

then

`pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6`. Make sure you have libcurl installed as well or you might experience install failures.

After restarting php5-fpm and my webserver (nginx) everything was working prefectly!

---

**EXTRA HELP:**

Before you install - and pear is installed - you may want to run these two commands assuming you are using the php.ini in fpm - or you can write the path according to your configuration: 
pear config-set php_ini /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

This makes it so that pecl knows which php.ini file you are using with your web-server and will add the extension=http.so in the correct spot. This helped me so maybe it'll help you too!

Comment: Good tip, but if still having trouble the following did it for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/360646/cant-use-php-extension-mcrypt-in-ubuntu-13-10-nginx-php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

When I installed one package from AUR:

> pecl_http

and I uncomment pecl_http PHP extension:

> extension=http.so

in the file:

> /etc/php/conf.d/http.ini

From this command:

> php test.php

I got:

> PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'http' because required module 'iconv' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0

Removing comment:

> extension=iconv.so

in the file:

> /etc/php/php.ini

solved the problem.

Linux distribution: Manjaro ( Arch Linux based ).